# Ruby: Creating an "attr_accessor :arg1, :arg2, :arg3" functionality

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, attr-accessor

So I want to be able to define a class like this:

```
class MyHouse < Home
  things :bed, :lamp, :chair
end
```

Where Home takes care of putting those "things" in an array, like this:

```
class Home
  attr_accessor :things

  def things(*things)
    @things = []
    things.each { |thing| @things << thing }
  end
end
```

The problem with this is I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `things' for MyHouse:Class
```

I know there's a way to do this. Help appreciated,

Thanks,

Pachun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def things` should be `def self.things`

That makes it a class method rather than an instance method.